# Pairing of Sigma and Pi in notation

Tags: soft-question, notation

Why do $ \Sigma $ and $ \Pi $ appear together so frequently in related topics. For example:

- Product and Sums
- Borel sets, such as $ \Sigma_0^1, \Pi_0^1 $
- First order formulas, such as $ \Sigma_1, \Pi_1 $.
- $ \sigma $ and $ \pi $ bonds

Comment: $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ are also obsolete notations for $\exists$ and $\forall$ and are the ultimate source of the use of these letters to denote formulas in the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) and related hierarchies of formulas. The $\sigma$ and $\pi$ bonds in chemistry are unrelated; they ultimately come from the initial letters of the adjectives ‘sharp’ and ‘principal’; [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).

Answer (score 0):

It's not esoteric, it's just a convenient mnemonic.

The Greek letter Sigma is to S, as Pi is P. Hence the symbols are used for Sums and Products, or related concepts, or for Symmetrical and Pairwise bonds (of the s, p, and d orbitals).